# SQL server equivalent of MySQL's "SHOW VARIABLES"

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to retrieve some information from a SQL Server database.

For example, I'd like the number of authorized, the number of queries connections or others...

With a MySQL database, I can have it with this query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES;
```

This returns me a result like:

[image]

Is there an equivalent for SQL Server?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you running?

Answer (score 4):

[`sp_configure`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188787.aspx) will show current configuration parameters. For other information, reffer to the appropriate [catalog view](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365.aspx) or [management view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188754.aspx). Eg. [sys.dm_exec_connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509.aspx) will show the number of connections, [sys.dm_exec_requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx) will show the executing requests and so on and so forth.

Comment: When I want to retrieve the result of this view sys.dm_exec_connections , I get thie error : 

`Error:   The object 'dm_exec_requests' does not exist in database 'testsqlserver' or is invalid for this operation.
Source:   .Net SqlClient Data Provider`

Do I need root privileges?

For information I am in plesk panel.

Comment: No, you need to refrain from renaming objects. It is called `sys.dm_exec_requests`, the schema part is important.

Comment: I just found [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173823.aspx)

I can have `MAX_CONNECTION` And the SQL Server Version, but I don't know how to get the queries limit per hour.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sp_helpdb DATABASENAME`.  That will give you basic info about collation, version etc.  Connection info is available under System Views (SSMS), but you can also `execute sp_who2` and that will give you good info on who is currently connected.